# Salesforce apex:commandButton does not execute the action

Tags: salesforce, apex, commandbutton

So I have this in the page:

```
< apex:commandButton id="songdbabc" value="Synch from song db" action="{!sendingSign}" />
```

and this in the controller:

```
public PageReference  sendingSign(){
    System.debug(' message ');
    return null;
}
```

But everytime I press the button there isn`t any message in the "Log" I mean the action is not executed , any idea?

Comment: This question needs more information to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another variable or function with same name? I mean `public String sendingSign {get; set;}` or maybe `public String getSendingSign()`? These would "shadow" your action function. Do you have more than 1 controller extension in `<apex:page>` tag? they'd be checked for matching function names from right to left (so if you have few classes maybe it's calling the match from a class you're not looking at)

Open up your browser's JS console / network panel, see if there's any traffic recorded at all when you click the button...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but not, I dont have any atribute or method with the same name or more controllers (just have one)

Comment: Out of ideas for now. Can you post more code (try to cut down the page & class to smallest example that still reproduces the issue). What does your debug log say when you click the button? Nothing at all, not even entering & leaving the method? Are you sure the class saved/compiled OK?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sendingSign method to :

```
public void sendingSign(){
    System.debug(' message ');
}
```

And recheck your log.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**  Fixed! Removed "Static" variables from my extension; all bad behavior cleared right up.

**Original:**
I had to build a stackoverflow account just so I could vent a little here. I'm facing the same issue, and found that it will only skip my action if I include a picklist on the same page. I've never had this issue.

this page runs the action, but doesn't include the picklist I want:

```
<apex:page standardController="Checklist_Template_Item__c" recordSetVar="Checklist_Template_Items__r" extensions="ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!myCustomAction}" value="Append/Remove" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
        <apex:variable value="{!appendValue}" var="appendValue"/>
        <apex:variable value="{!selection}" var="selection"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >                    
            Include your selected items for select machine models.
            <apex:inputText value="{!appendValue}"/>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

this page completely skips the action, but includes my picklist:

```
<apex:page standardController="Checklist_Template_Item__c" recordSetVar="Checklist_Template_Items__r" extensions="ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!myCustomAction}" value="Append/Remove" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
        <apex:variable value="{!appendValue}" var="appendValue"/>
        <apex:variable value="{!selection}" var="selection"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >                    
            Include your selected items on certain machine models.
            <apex:inputText value="{!appendValue}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputText value="Why tho"/>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selection}" required="true">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!applyRemove}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

having either a page constructor or not, action doesn't run when the picklist is included:

extension v1:

```
public without sharing class ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply{

public static String appendValue{get;set;}
public static String selection{get;set;}
public static List<SelectOption> applyRemove{get;set;}

ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

public ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply(ApexPages.StandardSetController myController){
    setCon = myController;

    List<String> addList = new List<String>{'Applies_To__c'};
    setCon.addFields(addList);

    system.debug('addList = '+addList);

    applyRemove = new List<SelectOption>();
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('Include','Include'));
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('Remove','Remove'));

}

public ApexPages.pageReference myCustomAction(){
    system.debug('hey');

    PageReference returnPage = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
    system.debug('returnPage = '+returnPage);

    return returnPage;
}
}
```

extension V2:

```
public without sharing class ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply{

public static String appendValue{get;set;}
public static String selection{get;set;}
public static List<SelectOption> applyRemove{get;set;}

ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

public ChecklistTemplateItemMassApply(ApexPages.StandardSetController myController){
    setCon = myController;

    List<String> addList = new List<String>{'Applies_To__c'};
    setCon.addFields(addList);

    system.debug('addList = '+addList);

    applyRemove = new List<SelectOption>();
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('Include','Include'));
    applyRemove.add(new SelectOption('Remove','Remove'));

}

public void ApexPages.pageReference myCustomAction(){
    system.debug('hey');
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for posting your answer. Please, improve your response. It looks full of code out of the context of the question.